# path variable of yarn

Tags: linux, yarnpkg

I have installed yarn in my 16.04 LTS version according to this tutorial [tutorial](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install)

have added the environment path as well, but the termial does not take any yarn commands.

on typing yarn init, it gives ::-

```
ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'init'
```

same for when i type yarn global bin ::-

```
ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'global'
```

I think it is because of the PATH variable issue, can anyone tell me what else i need to add.

Thanks

Comment: Did you *do* ```export PATH="$PATH:`yarn global bin`"```?

Comment: yes in my .bashrc

Comment: And you've verified that it puts whatever it puts there with something like `echo $PATH`?

Comment: yes /usr/bin/yarn is in my $PATH

Comment: what's the output of `which yarn`? (I followed the instructions on a docker ubuntu 16.04 container and it worked flawlessly, so...)

Comment: which yarn gives - usr/bin/yarn

Comment: And `yarn --version`?

Comment: version is 0.22 @wayneWerner

Answer (score 4):

So i found the resolution to this problem . their is a package called cmdtest which was installed in my system, which also contained a package called yarn.
This yarn was conflicting with the yarnpkg, and when i was running yarn init or any other yarn commands it was probably running that yarn package with the argument, hance the error. the `yarn --version` and `which yarn` was running correctly which further convoluted the issue. i uninstalled cmdtest and installed yarn again which fixed the issue. More details about this issue can be found in [this](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2016/11/msg00100.html) bug report